# Show an image from b&w to color as if it were loading (left to right)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't know how to make clearer the title of the question.

I have an effect where it shows a text with grey color and with keyframes in css the characters become black with the animate css property.

I wonder how could I acomplish that effect but with an image, transitioning from b&w to color from the left to the right.

This is the code:

```
    <div class="modal">
        <h1 id="testid" data-content="THIS&nbsp;IS&nbsp;A&nbsp;TEST">THIS&nbsp;IS&nbsp;A&nbsp;TEST</h1>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes loading{
    from{max-width:0}
}

@-moz-keyframes loading{
    from{max-width:0}
}

@-o-keyframes loading{
    from{max-width:0}
}

@keyframes loading{
    from{max-width:0}
}

.modal {
background:#fff;
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index:9999999;
}

.modal h1 {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-top:-15px;
margin-left:-125px;
font-size:30px;
text-align:center;
color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.modal h1:before {
content:attr(data-content);
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
color:#000;
max-width:100%;
-webkit-animation:loading 5s;
-moz-animation:loading 5s;
-o-animation:loading 5s;
-ms-animation:loading 5s;
animation:loading 5s;
}
```

The code running here: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vmnn/

Thank you

Comment: the css animation core only slides a single value for animation, like one color to the next. it can do many pairs at once, but it can't mashup two different things like size and color to be exclusive of eachother while animating. you might be able to reveal a color copy over the black and white, but you'll likely need script, not just css.

Comment: Could you not have 2 divs, each containing an image, one b+w and one colour and have the width of the colour DIV slowly expand similar to above? Just make sure the images have their full width set but the parent div's width would clip it

Comment: if you have 2 versions of the image (one is b&w and the other is color), you can achieve this effect, otherwise (do not have b&w version), you may have to use `filter` for webkit-based browsers and  `svg` for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you were thinking of something like this?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gez9F/1)

It's *not* greyscale, but it provides a similar effect.

**EDIT:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gez9F/3/)'s a version for Webkit with greyscale using `-webkit-filter` (still right-to-left...)

I've changed your overlay to use opacity, but the principle is the same:

```
.modal {
 opacity: 0.8;
background:black;
z-index:9999999;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
max-width:0;
-webkit-animation:loading 5s;
-moz-animation:loading 5s;
-o-animation:loading 5s;
-ms-animation:loading 5s;
animation:loading 5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: nice, I think with your example I have something to work on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would make an animated GIF which I think is far easier.

Make 5-10 images each a varying amount b&w and colour and then use ImageMagick to make an animated GIF out of them with a single line like this:

```
convert -delay 20 -loop 0  *.jpg  animated.gif
```

You may want `loop=1` for a single loop, whereas I have it set to zero for infinite looping in the example.

[image]
[image]
[View animated GIF here](http://thesetchells.com/animated.gif)

In case you are not familiar with Photoshop, I added a Hue Saturation layer and cranked the Saturation down to zero making a black and white image. Then I pressed `G` for Gradient Tool and drew a horizontal line across the image to specify where the transition is from B&W to colour whilst holding the Shift key to ensure it was horizontal. Then saved it as a 1.jpg and redrew the gradient in a different place and saved it again as 2.jpg and so on.

Comment: Nice GIF. I like how you've hosted this on your site that specialises in black and white photography. ;)